# Failed to connect to SFTP on Windows Server

Tags: windows, windows-10, openssh, sftp, winscp

I used this guide to install OpenSSH from [WinSCP's](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server) website.

I used the `msi` installer that is listed on the github page https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases.

The server seems to be running but after trying to login I get:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Connection has been unexpectedly closed. Server sent command exit status 1.
---------------------------
Cannot initialize SFTP protocol. Is the host running an SFTP server?
---------------------------
OK   Reconnect   Help   
---------------------------
```

On the server machine there seems to be an sshd running and listening on port 22 (copied from TCPview) :

| Process | PID | Protocol | State | Local Address | Local Port | Remote Address | Remote Port | Create Time | Module name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sshd.exe | 5844 | TCP | Listen | 0.0.0.0 | 22 | 0.0.0.0 | 0 | 8/19/2022 6:49:33 PM | sshd |
| sshd.exe | 5844 | TCPv6 | Listen | :: | 22 | :: | 0 | 8/19/2022 6:49:33 PM | sshd |

I have not changed the default `sshd_config`

## Update:

Using putty and the same user name and password works and I can browse directories.

Here's putty vs WinScp:

[image: putty_vs_winscp]

(Where red and orange are username and machine name respectively)

### FW rules are defined:

[image: Firewall_rules]

Comment: How exactly are you trying to connect?  Is port 22 open on the server's firewall?

Comment: Using WinSCP and the machine name of the "server" machine. I believe it does create FW rules as part of the setup, I can see allow rules for port 22 in the inbound rule list: https://imgur.com/a/iiEoFBB

Comment: Using putty and the same user name and password works and I can browse directories. @squillman

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the WinSCP and putty connections (recommend you paste them into the question instead of imgur)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was that `sftp-server.exe` was not in `PATH`.
Adding the installation path `C:\Program Files\OpenSSH` and restarting the service with `Restart-Service sshd` solved the issue.

I diagnosed by setting

```
SyslogFacility LOCAL0
LogLevel DEBUG3
```

in `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config`

And noticing that it complained about not finding it

```
subsystem: cannot stat sftp-server.exe: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the problem, open of SSH server config on Windows (usually located at `C:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config`).

---

First, replace `sftp-server.exe` with line `<absolute-path-to>/sftp-server.exe`.

It seems that setting `PATH` is useless on my side.

---

Second, comment or remove lines beginning with `ForceCommand` if exists.

It helps resolve most of the unknown errors from SFTP clients. However, there is a side effect that SSH clients will use CMD as the default shell.

To use PowerShell as the default shell edit SSH client config (usually located at`~/.ssh/config`):

```
Host <host>
  ...
  RemoteCommand powershell
```